# sed: capturing a recurring regex group that happens to be optional

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed, regex-group

I have some files named as shown in the examples below:

```
2000_A_tim110_may112_AATT_V22_P001_R1_001_V23_P007_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_BB_tim110_may112_AAMM_V14_P002_R1_001_V45_P008_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_C_tim110_DDFF_V18_P006_R1_001.ext
2000_DD_may112_EEJJ_V88_P004_R1_001.ext
```

From these filenames, I would like to extract the leading `2000_[A-Z]{1,2}` and ALL instances the `V[0-9]{2}` regex patterns.

That is,

From

```
2000_A_tim110_may112_AATT_V22_P001_R1_001_V23_P007_R2_001_comb.ext
```

I'd like to have

```
2000_A_V22_V23
```

And from

```
2000_DD_may112_EEJJ_V88_P004_R1_001.ext
```

I'd like to have

```
2000_DD_V88
```

I've been trying to achieve this with `sed` but I've not had any success thus far.

At first--rather naively--I tried

```
find *.ext | sed -r 's/^(2000_[A-Z]{1,2}).*(V{1}[0-9]{2,3}).*(V{1}[0-9]{2,3}).*\.ext/\1_\2_\3/'
```

And that yielded:

```
2000_A_V22_V23
2000_BB_V14_V45
2000_C_tim110_DDFF_V18_P006_R1_001.ext
2000_DD_may112_EEJJ_V88_P004_R1_001.ext
```

Which is not quite what I wanted, since two of the filenames here have returned unedited.

Then, having read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16719369/9494044), I tried making the group being captured in the middle optional like so:

```
find *.ext | sed -r 's/^(2000_[A-Z]{1,2}).*(V{1}[0-9]{2})?.*(V{1}[0-9]{2}).*\.ext/\1_\2_\3/'
```

But this didn't seem to have worked either since it returned

```
2000_A__V23
2000_BB__V45
2000_C__V18
2000_DD__V88
```

(i.e., the capturing group in the middle seems to have been skipped entirely.)

My question is, how do I get the following result?

```
2000_A_V22_V23
2000_BB_V14_V45
2000_C_V18
2000_DD_V88
```

Where am I going wrong? Or conversely, what am I missing? I'm very new to `sed` and `regex`--and I'd like to learn to use both well--so pointers and guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is at least extremely hard to do in `sed` — I'd almost be ready to say 'not possible', but that's probably not quite right.  You'd probably have to repeatedly delete the bits you didn't want, which `sed` can do (labels, test and branch, though the negative patterns make life complex; the patterns can probably leverage the underscores before and after), but it is neither simple nor obvious.

Comment: If you want an education in sed, we can give you a sed solution. If you want a simple solution that works, you should choose a different tool.

Comment: @Beta, I would not mind receiving said education (so long as it isn't too much of a bother for you/the educator). As a newbie, it's rather hard to figure out which tool is appropriate for the task at hand--e.g., Ed Morton has posted a neat answer that uses `awk` which I've never really used before, but have variously encountered being touted as a tool comparable to `sed`. I feel any information you provide me here would help me understand these tools and their relative advantages/disadvantages better.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler no need for hard tools in sed, just an alternation `|` operator should do this job. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246055/sed-capturing-a-recurring-regex-group-that-happens-to-be-optional#comment100992952_57246055), it is very hard to do the job in `sed`.  However, with careful use of branching and testing, it can be done.

I'm using the classic `sed` BRE notation; if you choose to use the more modern but not necessarily as portable ERE notation, you can eliminate a fair number of backslashes.  I also saved the script in a file, `sed.script`, and the sample data in a file `data`, and ran the command using:

```
$ sed -f sed.script data
2000_A_V22_V23
2000_BB_V14_V45
2000_C_V18
2000_DD_V88
$
```

The script contains:

```
:retry
s/^\(2000_[A-Z]\{1,2\}\(_V[0-9][0-9]\)*\)_[^_]\{1,\}$/\1/
t
s/^\(2000_[A-Z]\{1,2\}\(_V[0-9][0-9]\)*\)_[^_]\{1,\}_/\1_/
t retry
```

- The first line sets a label `retry`.
- The first `s///` line looks for `2000_` followed by one or two upper-case letters, then a sequence of zero or more instances of an underscore, a V and two digits (this is all remembered); then an underscore and a sequence of one or more non-underscores and the end of line.  This is replaced by the remembered material.
- If the first `s///` matched, then it branches to the end of script (`t` with no label name).  This results in the line being printed.
- The second `s///` line is very similar to the first, except that instead of looking for the end of line, it looks for another underscore after the underscore and sequence of non-underscores.  Note that the term that looks for `_V##` (where `#` represents a digit) finds as many of them as possible, so the `_xxx_` term does not match `_V##_`.  That is replaced by the remembered term and an underscore, so it deletes one unit of `_xxx_` from the string.
- If the second `s///` matched, then it branches back to the start of the script.
- In theory, if the second `s///` does not match, then the loop is broken and what's left is printed.  In practice, it is not reached with the sample data, but if an input line did not match at all (e.g. it started `2001` instead of `2000`), then it would be printed unchanged after not being worked on by either of the `s///` operations.
- If lines that do not match the start pattern should be deleted, that can be handled by adding a line at the start of the script:

  ```
  /^2000_[A-Z]\{1,2\}/!d
  ```
- If lines that do not contain any `_V##_` sequences, that too can be dealt with, adding more lines before the `retry` label.  If there's `_V##` at the end of a line (and nowhere sooner), then it skips past the next line.  The next line looks for `_V##_` in the middle of a line and deletes the line if there's no match.

  ```
  /_V[0-9][0-9]$/b skip
  /_V[0-9][0-9]_/!d
  :skip
  ```

You can see how this progresses by adding `p` after each `s///` operation, which shows the intermediate results too:

```
2000_A_may112_AATT_V22_P001_R1_001_V23_P007_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_A_AATT_V22_P001_R1_001_V23_P007_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_A_V22_P001_R1_001_V23_P007_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_A_V22_R1_001_V23_P007_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_A_V22_001_V23_P007_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_A_V22_V23_P007_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_A_V22_V23_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_A_V22_V23_001_comb.ext
2000_A_V22_V23_comb.ext
2000_A_V22_V23
2000_A_V22_V23
2000_BB_may112_AAMM_V14_P002_R1_001_V45_P008_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_BB_AAMM_V14_P002_R1_001_V45_P008_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_BB_V14_P002_R1_001_V45_P008_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_BB_V14_R1_001_V45_P008_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_BB_V14_001_V45_P008_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_BB_V14_V45_P008_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_BB_V14_V45_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_BB_V14_V45_001_comb.ext
2000_BB_V14_V45_comb.ext
2000_BB_V14_V45
2000_BB_V14_V45
2000_C_DDFF_V18_P006_R1_001.ext
2000_C_V18_P006_R1_001.ext
2000_C_V18_R1_001.ext
2000_C_V18_001.ext
2000_C_V18
2000_C_V18
2000_DD_EEJJ_V88_P004_R1_001.ext
2000_DD_V88_P004_R1_001.ext
2000_DD_V88_R1_001.ext
2000_DD_V88_001.ext
2000_DD_V88
2000_DD_V88
```

If your `sed` supports extensions over what POSIX [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) requires, you may be able to simplify the script.  For example, there may be options to simplify the script if you can use `|` or `+`.  This should work with any version of `sed`.

This code was tested with both macOS (BSD) `sed` and with GNU `sed` and works the same with both.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer @Jonathan Leffler. I'm really grateful for the step-by-step explanations, and I'm also impressed by the fact that you've covered outlier scenarios.

Comment: I think a simpler solution is possible: `:a<CR>/^2000_[A-Z]*\(_V[0-9]\{2\}\)*$/b<CR>s/\(^2000_[A-Z]*\(_V[0-9]\{2\}\)*\)_[^_]*/\1/<CR>ba`

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='^2000_[A-Z]{1,2}|V[0-9]{2}' '{out=$1; for (i=2; i<=NF;i++) out=out "_" $i; print out}' file
2000_A_V22_V23
2000_BB_V14_V45
2000_C_V18
2000_DD_V88
```

Answer (score 1):

As a pure `bash` solution (sorry, without `sed`), how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

pat='((^2000_[A-Z]{1,2})|(_V[0-9]{2}))(.*)'
while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
    result=
    while [[ $line =~ $pat ]]; do
        result+="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        line="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    done
    [[ -n "$result" ]] && echo "$result"
done < <(find . -type f -name '*.ext' -printf '%f\0')
```

output:

```
2000_A_V22_V23
2000_BB_V14_V45
2000_C_V18
2000_DD_V88
```

Answer (score 1):

What's hard with basic sed? Make use the power of alternation `|` operator with sed's substitute functionality.

```
$ cat sedtets 
2000_A_tim110_may112_AATT_V22_P001_R1_001_V23_P007_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_BB_tim110_may112_AAMM_V14_P002_R1_001_V45_P008_R2_001_comb.ext
2000_C_tim110_DDFF_V18_P006_R1_001.ext
2000_DD_may112_EEJJ_V88_P004_R1_001.ext

$ sed 's/\(2000_[A-Z]\{1,2\}\|_V[0-9]\+\)\|./\1/g' sedtets
2000_A_V22_V23
2000_BB_V14_V45
2000_C_V18
2000_DD_V88
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nqxSKG/1)

Logic here is to capture all the necessary parts using a single capturing group and then match all the remaining characters.

Then replace the all the matched, captured chars with captured chars. This will keep only captured chars and deletes all the matched chars.

Comment: The `sed` script shown does not work with macOS (BSD) `sed`, with or without the `-E` (extended regular expression) option.  GNU `sed` does accept it without needing the `-E` option.  However, given a line `2001_DD_V96`, it outputs `_V96`.  Given a line `2000_BB_tim110_may112_AAMM_P002_R1_001_P008_R2_001_comb.ext` with no `_V##` in it, it outputs `2000_BB`.  Granted, those weren't in the data in the question, so it isn't clear what the correct behaviour is, but it is likely that neither line should generate any output.  The `2001_DD…` line certainly doesn't match the required `2000_…` prefix.

Comment: The `2000_` prefix can be handled by changing `find *.ext |` into `find 2000_*.ext |`

Comment: We don't need to go for find even, if we use the same regex (without slashes) in rename utility

Comment: Could you please explain why it's necessary to use the `|` operator here? Although I accepted @Jonathan Leffler's answer as it was educational, I must confess that the solution you've presented here would be the most straightforward one. As you both can guess, the data doesn't have discrepancies such as `2001_` instead of `2000_` among the filenames and so forth. Perhaps I should have clarified this in the OP; I did not foresee people thinking so far out from what was presented in the question. : ) : )

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` with a loop:

```
for f in $(find 2000* -regex '2000_[A-Z].*ext'); do
    printf "%s\n" $(grep -Eo "^2000_[A-Z]{1,2}|_V[0-9]{2}" <<<"$f" | tr -d "\n")
done
```